# How to create a mutable array of specific class type in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mutable

I have a class called `Bullet` and I want to make a mutable array with this class type. Basically the desired outcome I want is, when a user touches the screen a new bullet is spawned. I know in Java you can use an `ArrayList` to achieve this by adding a new instance to the array list each time.

I'm not sure syntactically how I could achieve in Swift or if it is even possible. 
This is the code I have for declaring and instance of the `Bullet` class but how do I make it so that it is a mutable array...

```
var bullet: Bullet = Bullet()
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not even trying to learn Swift.

Comment: Learning how to make a mutable array in Swift??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simple :

```
var bulletArray = [Bullet]() // this will declare and initialize the bulletArray
```

In the above line of code the type is inferred for the bulletArray.

If you explicitly want to specify the type then,

```
var bulletArray:[Bullet] = [Bullet]() // this will declare and initialize the bulletArray
```

If you just want to declare the array but not initialize then

```
var bulletArray:[Bullet]
```

If you just declare the array then you need to initialize it in init() before using it. Or else you can declare array as optional type. As shown below,

```
var bulletArray: [Bullet]?
```

HTH :)

Comment: In the last version you'll either need to make it optional or instantiate it in the init method. :)

Answer (score 2):

To create a typed array...

```
var bulletArray: [Bullet] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

A mutable array in Swift is an array with a mutable reference:

```
var bulletList = [Bullet]()
```

Now you can add Bullet objects at will...